# Set dynamic key in state via useState React hooks

Tags: reactjs

I want to set dynamic state with dynamic key by [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) in it in functional component 
Below is example with the class based Component in React

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    [uuid()]: []
  };
```

How can achieve this with functional component ?

```
const App = props=>{
 const [list, setList] = useState([uuid()]);
```

I tried using above approach it gives me output

`["4b4c8872-0c35-49a6-a98b-ef7abcb2cef8"]`

but desired is
`["4b4c8872-0c35-49a6-a98b-ef7abcb2cef8": []]`

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I believe you're looking for an object. ["4b4c8872-0c35-49a6-a98b-ef7abcb2cef8": []] is not executable syntax in javascript

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass in an object instead of an array to `useState`

```
const App = props=>{
 const [list, setList] = useState({ [uuid()] : [] });
```

If you want to append new keys to the state value, you can do the following.

```
addList = (e) => {
    setList({
      ...list,  //take existing key-value pairs and use them in our new state,
      [uuid()]: []   //define new key-value pair with new uuid and [].
    })
}
```

Comment: @akshay Awesome! Glad that worked for you, let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: How can I append more state keys in it for e.g. ```addList = e => {
    this.setState({ [uuid()]: [] });
  };``` in it?

Comment: @akshay, you can use the setList method that came with your useState(). In the method, we would just spread the existing state, and then add a new list as a key. See my updated solution :)